# C#: Gets unmatched elements between 2 collections with Linq & Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have two collections, compare them and want to get the unmatched items and put into a new collection. I don't want to use conventional method using 2 foreach loop. How to implement it using linq and lambda expression?
e.g.

```
    int[] collection1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int[] collection2 = new int[] { 2, 3 };
    // Goal: Using Linq and Lambda Expression: the new collection3 should contain 1, 4, 5
```

Edited: sorry I forget to mention: collection2 is a subset of collection1, therefore all elements in collection2 must exist in collection1.

Comment: Please clarify: what should be the result, if the collections are `{1,2}` and `{2,3}`?

Comment: Hi Henrik, thank you. I have edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = collection1.Except(collection2).Concat(collection2.Except(collection1)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
int[] collection3 = collection1.Except(collection2).ToArray();
```

Comment: I think you need to do another `Except` the other way round

Answer (score 3):

```
int[] collection3 = collection1.Union(collection2).Except(collection1.Intersect(collection2)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**Enumerable.Except Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx):

```
var result = collection1.Except(collection2);
```

As mentioned in the comments, if also the unique elements from the second collection should be added, your code would look like:

```
var result = collection1.Except(collection2).Concat(collection2.Except(collection1));
```